# iOS: how do you use URL as names of file?

Tags: ios, url, encoding

I mean how to encode the URL so that it can be converted to a string compatible as a file name, and also it can be decoded back to original URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [Download base64 encode / decode class](http://www.imthi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip)
then use the below Code to encode and Decode.

For encoding :

```
[Base64 initialize];

NSString *str=@"http://www.cogzentappz.com";

NSData *data1 = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *data2=[Base64 encode:data1];

NSLog(@"data2=%@",data2);
```

For Decoding below Code :

```
 NSData * data3 = [Base64 decode:data2]; // data2 is encoded string

NSString * actualString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"actualString=%@",actualString);
```